# Greenplum | gpbackup | Error=> error message: 5: write error (SQLSTATE 22P04)

Tags: greenplum

Need a help on below error

I am running a gpbackup and gpbackup is failing with below error message

20201109:21:06:04 gpbackup:gpinapsp:pgpm201.amfam.com:010755-[CRITICAL]:-ERROR: Error from segment 56: ERROR:  command error message: 5: write error (SQLSTATE 22P04)

I tried with exclude schema and include schema both

FYI, Greenplum Version => 4.3.33.3

FYI, Im first time trying gpbackup, backup is running since long via gpcrondump utility

Thanks

Comment: Are you backing up to local disk? S3? If local disk, do you have backup directory/mountpoint (if NFS) that is writable by gpadmin:gpadmin on all segment hosts? backup directory should have the same name/location on all segment hosts. If S3, is your bucket writable? Regards,
Jim

Comment: Yes Im writting to local, Yes Mount point have same name and they are witable